# Code in $(document).ready, sometimes works sometimes doesnt

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to dynamically map data from one object to another in an $(document).ready() function, the problem is that it works whenever it wants, the console.logs throughout the code are sometimes working, sometimes not.

```
var newBtnsObj = {};

$(document).ready(() => {
  robots.forEach((robot) => {
    newBtnsObj[robot.Name] = {};
    newBtnsObj[robot.Name].Buttons = {};

    console.log(newBtnsObj);

    Object.keys(robot.ConfigData).forEach((dataType) => {
      if (dataType === DataTypes.IO) {
        Object.values(robot.ConfigData[`${dataType}`]).forEach((IOData) => {

          if (IOData.length > 0) {
            IOData.forEach((s) => {
              console.log("HI");

              newBtnsObj[robot.Name].Buttons[s.HtmlID] = {
                DataType: dataType,
                ID: s.ID,
                Val: null,
              };

            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        Object.values(robot.ConfigData[`${dataType}`]).forEach((data) => {
          console.log("doublehi");

          newBtnsObj[robot.Name].Buttons[data.HtmlID] = {
            DataType: dataType,
            ID: data.ID,
            Val: null,
          };

        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**robots** is an array that is generated inside a socket.io event whenever someone connects to the page, I am using NodeJS on the backend to emit the "config" data that is used in the creation of the object and it is the first thing that is emitted when someone opens the page. I am opening the page locally and hosting the page and the server locally.

```
socket.on("config", (config) => {
  config.forEach((robot) => {
    robots.push(new Robot(robot.Name, robot.configData, robot.Events));
  });
```

The order in which I load the files in the HTML is first the socket file and then the file with the $(document).ready code.

The problem is that newBtnsObj is sometimes created, sometimes not, if I add any new code and refresh the page it works only on the first refresh and then it is again an empty object. But even that doesnt work everytime, I can't even reproduce it 100%.

Now just for completeness I have added the full code, but even if I remove the newBtnsObj creation and leave it only with the console.log("hi")'s I have the same issue, so the issue is not in the object creation itself (if I copy and paste the code in the browser console it works perfectly). So even if its left to this it still has the same issue:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  robots.forEach((robot) => {
    Object.keys(robot.ConfigData).forEach((dataType) => {
      if (dataType === DataTypes.IO) {
        Object.values(robot.ConfigData[`${dataType}`]).forEach((IOData) => {

          if (IOData.length > 0) {
            IOData.forEach((s) => {
              console.log("HI");             
            });
          }

        });
      } else {
        Object.values(robot.ConfigData[`${dataType}`]).forEach((data) => {
          console.log("doublehi");
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Additionally, I thought that the problem may be that, I am trying to use the robots array before it is created from the config received in the initial socket event, so I have tried placing the code within the event itself, so that it executes right after the event is received, and it worked. Obviously that is the issue, how can I solve it? Is the only way to keep the code in the socket event, and if I want to extract it, I have to make another internal event to let the code know that the robots array is ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you programmed yourself a *race-condition* there. So your jQuery is executed whenever the page is loaded, regardless if the `robots` object is there or not. But the generation of the object is related to connections and network timing too. So your script only runs fine, if the generation is faster as your page loading.

And now you might ask why it would not work, if you copy the code below the generation itself. That is a race-condition too. Code inside a jQuery ready state will only be executed after page load. If you paste the code inside another script, like the object generation, the ready state may be registered at a time, where the page was already loaded. So it will never be executed, because you registered it to late.

So what you need to do, is to ensure that the code is only executed after the generation is finished. Maybe by using a callback, an event or something else. But for now, you have two related scripts what run whenever they want and nobody waits for each other. ;)

---

By the way, just a hint: Using `$(document).ready(() => {})` is not best practice and out-dated too. There is a shorthand for that. And you should use `jQuery` instead of `$` for calling it, so your scripts will work in `noConflict` mode too. So insted use `jQuery(($) => {})`.